# функция подставления в строку аргументов

Tags: c++, linux, g++

есть функция

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf */
#include <stdarg.h>     /* va_list, va_start, va_arg, va_end */

void format (int n, ...)
{
  int i;
  double val;
  printf ("Printing floats:");
  va_list vl;
  va_start(vl,n);
  for (i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    val=va_arg(vl,double);
    printf (" [%.2f]",val);
  }
  va_end(vl);
  printf ("\n");
}

int main ()
{
  PrintFloats (3,3.14159,2.71828,1.41421);
  return 0;
}
```

1 вопрос, не могу сделать чтоб она считала сама аргументы и выводила все аргументы 
2 вопрос как сделать так чтоб я задава сам формат сообщения? ну чтоб я вызывал функцию например так format( " select * from where kod_tovara=%1 and imya=%2") 
подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> она считала сама аргументы

Что имеется в виду? Если речь о том, чтобы избавиться от параметра `n`, то либо вы передаёте количество аргументов явно, либо используете какой-то признак конца списка аргументов:

```
PrintFloats( 3.0, 3.14159, 2.71828, 1.41421, 0.0 );
// 0.0 (или любое другое заранее оговоренное 
// значение, например, -1970.0) - конец, больше аргументов не будет
```

> чтоб я вызывал функцию например так format( " select * from where kod_tovara=%1 and imya=%2")

Так и сделайте:

```
void format (const char * format, ...) {
```

Примеры реализации - в абсолютно любом гугляндексе с первых же ссылок по запросу типа "va_arg примеры" десятками сыплются. Смотрите, пробуйте. Даже в `man va_arg` примеры есть. В этом случае список аргументов будет браться из строки формата, и специально передавать их количество или признак конца не нужно.

Например, чуть переработаный пример из `man va_arg`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

static void format( const char * fmt, ... )
{
    union
    {
        double f;
        int d;
        char * s;
    } var;
    va_list ap;
    va_start( ap, fmt );
    while( *fmt )
    {
        if( *fmt == '%' )
        {
            fmt++;
            if( *fmt )
            {
                switch( *fmt )
                {
                    case 'f':
                        var.f = va_arg( ap, double );
                        printf( "%f", var.f );
                        break;

                    case 's':
                        var.s = va_arg( ap, char * );
                        printf( "%s", var.s );
                        break;

                    case 'd':
                        var.d = va_arg( ap, int );
                        printf( "%d", var.d );
                        break;

                    default:
                        printf( "%c", *fmt );
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf( "%c", *fmt );
        }
        fmt++;
    }
    va_end( ap );
}

int main()
{
    format( "int: %d, double: %f, string: %s\n", (int)1, (double)2, "3" );
    return 0;
}
```

P.S. Надеюсь, вы не всерьёз изобретаете свой велосипед для работы с БД? Если так - откажитесь поскорей от этой идеи и найдите нормальные готовые библиотеки.

Comment: а не могли бы вы привести пример как можно реализовать format("select * from where kod_tovara=%1 and imya=%2", kod_tovara,imya); уж чет либо туплю, либо пропускаю мимо глаз

Comment: `man va_arg` наберите, там есть секция "EXAMPLE" :-) OK, перепишу по-своему пример оттуда. Но если мановский пример не понятен - задавайте **конкретные** вопросы.